# SOLR and VNodes and Tokens

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

**Note: I have done a little reformatting and added some additional information.**

Please take a look at this: [Question_Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331235/running-search-workload-and-cassandra-workload-on-the-same-physical-node/28333325#28333325)

I want to ask - with DSE 5.0 and the upcoming changes that were mentioned at C* Summit this year for 5.1 and 5.2, will the same advice be useful?

Our use case is:

The platform MUST be available at all times. (Cassandra)
The data must be searchable. (SOLR / Lucene)
The platform MUST provide analytics / Data Warehousing / BI etc (Graph / Spark)

All of that is possible in a single product offering thanks to DSE! Thank you DataStax!

But our amount of data stored and our transaction count are VERY modest.
Our specification is for 100 concurrent sessions within the application - which of course doesn't even translate to 100 concurrent DB requests / operations.

For the most part our application resembles an everyday enterprise CRUD application.

While not ridiculous, AWS instances aren't exactly free.
Having a separate cluster for each workload (with enough replication for continuous availability), will be a cost issue for us.

While I understand, a proof of concept can offer some help - but without a real workload / real users - passing through the services / applications - in ways that only a "production" system and rogue users : can really provide an insight for. The best you can do is "loaded" functional testing.

In short, we're a little stuck here from a platform perspective.

We're, initially, thinking of having:

2 data centres for geographic isolation
2 racks per DC
2 nodes per Rack
RF of 3
CL of local_quorum

If we find we're hitting performance issues, we can scale out - add an extra rack or extra nodes to the initial 2 racks.

As for V-nodes or number of tokens, we have no idea.

The documentation for DSE Search says V-nodes adds 30% overhead, so it sounds like you shouldn't use V-nodes, but then in a table in the documentation it also says to use 16 or 32. How can it be both?

If we can successfully run all workloads on a single node (our requirements are genuinely minimal), do we run with V-nodes (16 or 32) or do we run a single token?

Lastly, is there another alternative?
Can you have Nodes with different workloads in the same data centre? Where individual nodes are set up with RAM / CPU requirements for a specific workload?

Assuming our 4 node per data centre (as a starting place only - we have no idea whether or not you can successfully run Search on a single node / or Spark on a single node)

Node 1: Just Cassandra
Node 2 : Cassandra and Search
Node 3 : Cassandra and Graph
Node 4 : Cassandra and Spark

If Search needs 64GB RAM - so be it... but the Cassandra only node could well work with just 8 or 16.

So we can cater, in terms of CPU and memory per workload type - but still only have a single DC. (We'll have 2 for redundancy - but effectively it is a single DC installation : mirrored)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Vnodes adds an additional overhead for the scatter-gather part of the search solution.  In some benchmarks that's been as high as 30%.  Some customers are willing to live with that overhead and want to use vnodes due to the benefits of dynamic scaling.

If you have or are planning a small cluster - and won't need to scale it on the fly - then I would definitely recommend sticking with single tokens.  The hidden benefit of that approach, is that your repairs will be slightly faster also.  This helps with Search as you are reading at the equivalent of CL.ONE.

It is possible to run all the features on the same DC (Search, Analytics and now Graph) but you will find that the overheads go up. You will need larger nodes with more memory and cpu resources to cope with the processing load.  I'd probably start with 128 Gb of ram and go from there.  I guess if your load is *really* light you might get away with less.  As with everything benchmarking at the scale you're intending to run is key.

As an aside I'm not totally clear on your intentions re RF.  You kind of imply 2 nodes and RF=3.  I'm guessing it's just phrasing, but if not - it's worth noting you want at least as many nodes as the RF for best coverage!

Comment: WRT to RF; with 2 nodes per rack : and 2 racks - that gives 4 nodes in total to a data center. Unless I am missing something - which I of course might be - a RF of 3 would seem to work here.

Comment: Oh missed 2 racs - yeah that should be fine.

Comment: If you decide to use vnodes with DSE Search in 5.0.x (or earlier), keep in mind that you may need to tweak the size of your Solr filter cache to ensure query performance stays reasonable. (Of course, you should be using the DSE SolrFilterCache, which limits global memory usage, rather than the OSS Solr cache implementations.)